# Is there a way to keep two or more video elements synchronized using react?

Tags: reactjs, events, video, synchronization, media

Im looking for a way of keeping my video elements synchronised using state from a parent React components.

I've tried a few things like using `componentDidUpdate` which kind of works for the play/pause thing. But it wont work for setting `currentTime` because it ends up looping. But as far as i know its also pretty bad practice right?
Im lifting up `currentTime` state up to my `VideoContainer` but how to i update my children `VideoElement`? They are getting the `currentTime` state and play/pause/seeking events but im unsure how i should hook this up.

The following code is what i've got so far and kind of explains the setup:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const videos = [
    'video1.mp4',
    'video2.mp4',
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <VideoContainer videos={ videos } />
    </div>
  );
};


class VideoContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isPlaying: false,
    isSeeking: false,
    currentTime: 0
  };

  onPlay = (e) => {
    this.setState({isPlaying: true});
  };

  onPause = (e) => {
    this.setState({isPlaying: false});
  };

  onSeeking = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      isSeeking: true,
      isPlaying: false
    });
  };

  onSeeked = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      currentTime: e.target.currentTime,
      isSeeking: false,
      isPlaying: true
    });
  };

  onTimeUpdate = (e) => {
    this.setState({currentTime: e.target.currentTime});
  };

  render() {
    const { videos } = this.props;
    const { isPlaying, currentTime, isSeeking } = this.state;

    return (
      videos.map((video, i) => (
        <VideoElement
          key={i}
          src={video}
          isSeeking={isSeeking}
          isPlaying={isPlaying}
          currentTime={currentTime}
          onPlay={this.onPlay}
          onPause={this.onPause}
          onSeeking={this.onSeeking}
          onSeeked={this.onSeeked}
          onTimeUpdate={this.onTimeUpdate}
        />
      ))
    )
  }
}

class VideoElement extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      src,
      onPlay,
      onPause,
      onSeeking,
      onSeeked,
      onTimeUpdate
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <video
        controls
        width="480"
        ref="video"
        src={src}
        onPlay={onPlay}
        onPause={onPause}
        onSeeking={onSeeking}
        onSeeked={onSeeked}
        onTimeUpdate={onTimeUpdate}
      />
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Are you trying to sync the videos after the user seeked in one of them? Because otherwise you will need to throttle that somehow as the video will start to lag otherwise.

Comment: Yeah i can see how it would start to lag. Ideally the update should happen while the user is seeking in one of them. But it would be okay if the update happened after seeking too.